vue3.5 Pass a value to a child component but the child component has not yet been mounted
Parent component ：
When clicked, the dialog map component opens and updates the values that need to be passed
function editPowerStationChooseMap() {
    mapVisible.value = true;
    mapForm.address = null
    mapForm.fullDddress = editPowerStationForm.value.address;
    editAddressInfo.value = editPowerStationForm.value.address;
}

<el-dialog v-model="mapVisible" title="选择位置" width="70%">
        <template #header>
            <el-form  :inline="true" ref="mapFormRef" :model="mapForm">
                <el-form-item label="省市区" prop="address">
                    <el-cascader v-model="mapForm.address" :filterable="true" :options="addressOption.option" :props="cascaderProps" class="custom-cascader" @change="chooseAddress" style="width: 240px"/>
                </el-form-item>
                <el-form-item label="详细地址" prop="fullDddress">
                    <el-input v-model="mapForm.fullDddress" placeholder="请输入详细地址" style="min-width: 400px"/>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-form>
        </template>
        <Map @mapReady="handleMapReady" :addressInfo="addressInfo":editAddressInfo="editAddressInfo"/>
        <span slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
  <el-button @click="mapVisible = false">取消</el-button>
  <el-button type="primary" @click="confirmAddress">确定</el-button>
</span>
    </el-dialog>

children component:
const emit = defineEmits(["mapReady"]);
const { addressInfo, editAddressInfo } = defineProps({
    addressInfo: {
        type: String,
    },
    editAddressInfo: {
        type: String
    }
});

watch([() => addressInfo, () => editAddressInfo], ([newAddress, newEditAddress], [oldAddress, oldEditAddress]) => {
    let addressToGeocode = '';
    // 判断是哪个值发生了变化
    if (newAddress !== oldAddress) {
        addressToGeocode = newAddress;
    } else if (newEditAddress !== oldEditAddress) {
        addressToGeocode = newEditAddress;
    }
    if (addressToGeocode) {
        geocoder.getLocation(addressToGeocode, function (status, result) {
            if (status === 'complete' && result.info === "OK") {
                const lnglat = result.geocodes[0].location;
                map.setCenter(lnglat);
                positionPicker.on('success', function (positionResult) {
                    detailedAddress.value = positionResult.address;
                    emit("mapReady", {
                        map,
                        geocoder,
                        detailedAddress,
                        positonInfo: [positionResult.position.lng, positionResult.position.lat]
                    });
                });
                positionPicker.on('fail', function (positionResult) {
                });
                positionPicker.start(lnglat);
            } else {
                console.error('根据地址查询位置失败');
            }
        });
    }
});

onMounted(() => {
    window._AMapSecurityConfig = {
        securityJsCode: '61ed75a46aa0cc6a2860aa025fd22ed5',
    };

    AMapLoader.load({
        key: '9c4e9341d7408b1241277ae9d7498df9',
        version: "2.0",
        AMapUI: {
            version: "1.1"
        }
    })
        .then((AMap) => {
            map = new AMap.Map("container", {
                viewMode: "2D",
                zoom: 11,
                center: [116.397428, 39.90923], // 默认中心点
            });


            // 拖拽选址插件
            AMapUI.loadUI(['misc/PositionPicker'], function (PositionPicker) {
                positionPicker = new PositionPicker({
                    mode: 'dragMarker',//设定为拖拽地图模式，可选'dragMap'、'dragMarker'，默认为'dragMap'
                    map: map, //依赖地图对象
                    iconStyle: {//自定义外观
                        url: ikun,
                        size: [48, 48],  //要显示的点大小，将缩放图片
                        ancher: [24, 40],//锚点的位置，即被size缩放之后，图片的什么位置作为选中的位置
                    }
                });
            });

            // Geocoder 插件
            AMap.plugin('AMap.Geocoder', () => {
                geocoder = new AMap.Geocoder({city: '全国'});
                emit("mapReady", {map, geocoder, detailedAddress: ''});
            });

        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.error(e);
        });
});

When I click, the dialog opens but the watch code does not execute. When I add the delayer, the code executes normally. like this:
function editPowerStationChooseMap() {
    mapVisible.value = true;
    setTimeout(()=>{
        mapForm.address = null
        mapForm.fullDddress = editPowerStationForm.value.address;
        editAddressInfo.value = editPowerStationForm.value.address;
    },500)
}

Trying nextTick didn't work either, was it because the map component took so long to load?

Does it work as intended if you add { immediate: true } as third parameter of watch()? See Eager watchers.

It didn't help. I really don't know what to do
